# Complex structure of HTML Bootstrap table

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I would like to create with BOOTSTRAP a complex structure of the table but I am not finding the solution.

Someone has the solution / HTML structure to provide me, please?  (in the screenshot, the structure I want to create)    :)

thanks,

(I use the version Bootstrap v3.3.6)

[Clicking here to see the image of the table wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv4d4.png)

Comment: You probably wont get any answers without providing what you tried, because its absolutely easy and doable with or without bootstrap

Comment: Research `colspan` and `rowspan`.

Comment: Please ask a concrete question and provide an example of what you already tried. If you are simply looking for examples, please do your own research first. If you cannot find examples that match your problem, ask a precise question what the examples you found are lacking.

Comment: Or go use a builder tool... https://buildbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `Bootstrap` class name as `colspan` and `rowspan` to achieve your desired table result. I saw your screenshot and maybe this is the output you want?

Here is the complete [Youtube tutorial](http://youtube.com/watch?v=-JMSCVbX2jY) for `colspan` and `rowspan`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    tr {
      border: teal 5px solid;
    }

    td {
      border: turquoise 5px solid;
    }

    td {
      border: tomato 5px solid;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table" style="text-align: center;">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Title-1</th>
      <th colspan="2">Title-2</th>
      <th>Title-3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">Row 1</td>
      <td colspan="2">Row 1-1</td>
      <td>Row 1-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1-2</td>
      <td>Row 1-2</td>
      <td>Row 1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2-1</td>
      <td>Row 2-1</td>
      <td>Row 2-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Row 2-2</td>
      <td>Row 2-2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```